# uWSGI chmod Socket to 666

Tags: uwsgi

When uWSGI prints `chmod() socket to 666 for lazy and brave users` in its log what does it mean exactly?

I'm not seeing anything in the docs about it. Though maybe I've not searched enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's logging the fact that you didn't explicitly specify the permissions for the socket and is telling you that it's done this for you:

> http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#chmod-socket

See:

> **`chmod-socket`**
>
> **Argument:** optional string
>
> Chmod socket.
>
> This option may be set with `-C` from the command line.
>
> UNIX sockets are filesystem objects that obey UNIX permissions like
>   any other filesystem object. You can set the UNIX sockets’ permissions
>   with this option if your webserver would otherwise have no access to
>   the uWSGI socket. **When used without a parameter, the permissions
>   will be set to 666. Otherwise the specified chmod value will be
>   used.**

Relevant source code in `socket.c`:

> https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/socket.c#L238-L251

Comment: Do you know if it's not just lazy but also brave? Are there any big security issues with setting it to 666?

Comment: @Christoffer - I honestly don't know, it would depend on your application's security requirements.

Comment: it say "brave" because it will execute a chmod 666 on the socket file, 666 means that every user can read and write from that file/socket so if you have a malicious access to the system or just some other process/user that want to mess around the system will not prevent them to read/write the socket file.